# AirFlow doesn't show messages from dataproc jobs

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to write my first dag in Airflow using pySpark in Dataproc, but I don't see a job's log message in the AirFlow UI. I see these messages in Dataproc UI. When I use `gcloud dataproc submit pyspark jobs` commands I see messages in console.

My dag

```
with DAG(
    'dag_1',
    default_args={'depends_on_past': False},
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    tags=['example'],
) as dag:

    task = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
        task_id='task_1', region=region, project_id=project_id,
        job={
            "reference": {"project_id": project_id},
            "placement": {"cluster_name": cluster_name},
            "pyspark_job": {
                "main_python_file_uri": pyspark_uri
            },
        }
    )

    task
```

My task

```
import logging
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    logger = logging.getLogger("airflow.task")
    logger.info('logger.info')
    spark = (SparkSession
             .builder
             .appName('test')
             .getOrCreate())
    print('print')
    logger.critical('logger.critical')
```

In Airflow UI I have only this

```
[2022-04-28, 12:50:02 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1446} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=dag_1
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=task_1
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-04-27T00:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2022-04-27T00:00:00+00:00
[2022-04-28, 12:50:02 UTC] {dataproc.py:1847} INFO - Submitting job
[2022-04-28, 12:50:02 UTC] {credentials_provider.py:312} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2022-04-28, 12:50:02 UTC] {dataproc.py:1859} INFO - Job 02d046aa-6e45-4889-a549-b2dcd44e9603 submitted successfully.
[2022-04-28, 12:50:02 UTC] {dataproc.py:1864} INFO - Waiting for job 02d046aa-6e45-4889-a549-b2dcd44e9603 to complete
[2022-04-28, 12:50:44 UTC] {dataproc.py:1868} INFO - Job 02d046aa-6e45-4889-a549-b2dcd44e9603 completed successfully.
```

I have Python 3.9 and Airflow 2.2.5

Comment: did u find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Having Dataproc logs in airflow UI will duplicate logging. However, you can navigate to the dataproc logs from Airflow UI using the Dataproc resource Link

[image]